# Make button appear after 10 seconds

Tags: vba, excel

I created one button and after my workbook loads, I want my button to appear after 10 seconds (not right away).

```
Dim ButtonOneClick As Boolean
Sub Button3_Click()
Sub disenable()
    Dim b1 As Button
    Set b1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Button3_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Button3_Click.Enabled = False
    DoEvents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    For i = 1 To 10
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
    Next i
    'Sheets(1).button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on activating the sheet or adjust to your needs

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Me.Buttons("Button 1").Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:10 AM#)
Me.Buttons("Button 1").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code is confusing, not mine. My code is simply an event in the Sheet module, where the current sheet can be referred to as "me". `Button 1` is a button with the name "Button 1". The code runs automatically when the sheet is activated. I said to adjust to your needs. Your code is confusing because it contains lots of things that don't make sense, like two opening `sub` lines, a `DoEvent` without anything getting done and AWFUL indentation.

Comment: Sub Buttons()

Me.Buttons("Buttons").Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:10 AM#)
Me.Buttons("Button 1").Visible = True

End Sub

Comment: That's what i have write now and getting an invalid .me user error, and i deleted my code now its not working at all im sorry im new at vba

Comment: Sheet events need to have the correct name. Use the code I posted. Make sure the button name is correct.

Comment: so my button name is Buttons.... or u want it Button1 and what does Me.Buttons mean

Comment: `Me` is the sheet that this code runs in. `Buttons` is the button collection in that sheet. `("Button 1")` is the button with the name "Button 1".  Start a new workbook. Create a button on Sheet1. Right click the sheet tab and select **View Code**. Paste the code I posted. Then click between the Sheet1 and other sheets. When the Sheet1 is activated, the code runs and the button appears after 10 seconds. On another note: this site is for professional and enthusiast programmers. Maybe you need a tutorial for beginners?